# String representation of negative int as hexadecimal characters

Tags: c

I wrote a function that receives an array and pointer and writes to the array the string representation of  int as hexadecimal characters.

```
void int_to_hexa_repr(char *arr, void *arg)
{
    int number = *(int*)arg;
    char const digit[] = "0123456789abcdef"; //hex digits
    char* pt = arr;

    if (number < 0)
    {
        *pt++ = '-';
        number *= -1;
    }

    int shifter = number;

    do
    {
        ++pt;
        shifter = shifter/16;
    } while (shifter);

    *pt = '\0';

    do
    {
        *--pt = digit[number%16];
        number = number/16;
    } while (number);
}
```

I check the function with tests files and I noticed that when I inserts a negative integer, the expected string representation is different than the actual result. For example, the expected result for int = -27 is ffffffe5 and my function returns -1b. 
For positive integer values the expected result and the actual result is equal. 
How can I change the function to deal correctly with negative integers?

Comment: You handle negative numbers by prepending a `-` and negating (if (number < 0) clause).  Why would you expect something different?  If you want to deal with `unsigned`, you should use `unsigned` instead of `int`

Comment: look up twos compliment.  that is how negative numbers are represented internally.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Handling negative numbers by printing “-”, then negating, then continuing with the code for positive numbers will fail for two’s complement `INT_MIN`, as negating it will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, the expected result for int = -27 is ffffffe5

Change your code to use `unsigned` to interpret an `int` as an `unsigned`.

```
  unsigned number = *(unsigned*)arg;
  ...
  unsigned shifter = number;
```